# Best way to learn how capybara and cucumber works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, bdd, capybara

I want to ask about the best resources to know how cucumber, capybara works. I know how to use them, but sometimes things go wrong I just don't know why, I thought about reading the capybara and cucumber source code, but It's a bit complicated without having a general idea about their work, so here's my question. How do you learn this things enough to understand whats happening behind and things doesn't seem like magic with tools like this?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber and Capybara are *fairly* independent, so you should try to learn about each one of them individually.

I haven't used Cucumber, but I assume the [web site](http://cukes.info/) with its wiki, examples and tutorials (see the navigation bar at the top) should be a great resource.

Regarding Capybara: Since the time you asked your question I've expanded the Capybara [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) a bit, so I recommend you check it out again.  You should be able to get going just by reading the README top to bottom (and perhaps following its pointers into the rdoc reference).  Capybara is not a very complex beast, really.

Answer (score 1):

For cucumber I would recommend reading either "The RSpec Book" from pragmatic press, or find the free download of a work in progress called "the secret ninja cucumber scrolls" http://cuke4ninja.com/